# Laravel event listeners undefined property error with ShouldQueue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have an event setup within my application that sends out an activation email upon the user signing up.  It works perfectly without the `ShouldQueue` interface.  However, when I add `implements ShouldQueue`, I get undefined property error:

> Undefined property: App\Events\User\UserCreated::$user

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners\User;

use App\Events\User\UserCreated;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Repos\Email\EmailTemplateRepoInterface;
use App\Repos\User\UserRepoInterface;
use Request, Mail, DbView;

class UserCreatedEmail implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(EmailTemplateRepoInterface $template)
    {
        $this->template = $template;
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  UserCreated  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserCreated $event)
    {
        $user = $event->user;

        if($user)
        {
            if(!$user->status)
            {
                $user->activation_url = Request::root().'/activate/'.$user->activation_code;
                $template = $this->template->findTemplateByName('new_user_activation');
                $userArr = $user->toArray();
            }

            Mail::queue([], [], function ($message) use ($template, $userArr) 
            {
                $message->to($userArr['email'])
                    ->subject($template->subject)
                    ->setBody(DbView::make($template)->with($userArr)->render(), 'text/html');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the `UserCreated` class as well:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events\User;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class UserCreated extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($user, $row, $request)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->row = $row;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

**Can anyone explain why this happens when I try to queue the email?**

Comment: The `UserCreated` instance does not have the property `user` set. Could you show us the class?

Comment: @Dencker - I have added the class above.

Answer (score 10):

You need to explicitly define the property as `public`. I.e.

```
class UserCreated extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;
    public $user;

...
```

Comment: I added this line to the top, now I get a different error `public $user, $row, $request;`......Error: Serialization of Closure is not allowed

Comment: This is an entirely other, seemingly [well-known](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/serialization-of-closure-is-not-allowed) problem with the Mailer class.

Comment: for laravel 5.1 it was working fine for me with "sync" connection but when I switched to any other connection it started giving me this error. Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: Thanks! `protected` worked for me.  Was easy to overlook in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#writing-job-classes).

Answer (score 0):

Like rdiz says add a `public` or `protected` property. If you still are experiencing issues be aware Laravel Event has some reserved properties, such as `sessionId` and `message`. Changing my parameter name to `sessionId_` solved it for me.